# phonegap media API or HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

which is better to use for playing mp3 files in iphone application the **phonegap media API** or the **html5 audio tag**?

Comment: I'm having the same question. Does the html5 audio API work via phonegap on android devices nowadays at all?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5's  tag will work with Phonegap, but your results will vary. Functions like audio.load() (assuming you're using javascript to control your HTML5 audio element) won't work. I would recommend using Phonegap's media API.

Answer (score 0):

A regular HTML5 audio tag will work in a Cordova project, even when you load music from the file system, if and only if you have a content security policy.
You can [create a content security policy online with this tool](http://cspisawesome.com/content_security_policies) or [study this great tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)
Note that the Cordova default project has a CSP, while the current default Phonegap project does not.